# When you press the button text disappears

Tags: html

He wants you press the button "Download" disappearing text.

```html
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="getInfo" onclick="getVideosInfo();">Download!</button>
    <div id="infobox">
      My TEXT
      </div>
```

Comment: It's very unclear what is the problem. Do you want the text to disappear when the button is clicked? Or does the text disappear and it shouldn't?

Comment: Who is this mysterious "He" you speak of and what have you tried to solve your problem?

Comment: He wants the text to disappear when you click the button.

Comment: Yes, I want to do to the text disappear when you press a button.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do, this code uses just 3 extra lines of jQuery code. Following is my solution:

```js
$('#getInfo').click(function(){
 $('#infobox').hide();
});

function getVideosInfo(){
  //...
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="getInfo" onclick="getVideosInfo();">Download!</button>
<div id="infobox">
  My TEXT
</div>
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/n8kg6ox1/) is an external fiddle supporting this.

Answer (score -1):

you need of course java script... but then it works like the following

```js
function getVideosInfo(){
  infobox = document.getElementById("infobox");
  infobox.style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="getInfo" onclick="getVideosInfo();">Download!</button>
<div id="infobox">
  My TEXT
</div>
```